# Trouble Receiving Subdomain Cookies in Express Backend with CORS and Cookie-Parser

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, wildcard-subdomain

I'm currently working on a MERN (MongoDB, Express, React, Node.js) application where I'm facing issues with receiving cookies from subdomains in my Express backend. I've set up CORS and cookie handling, and while everything works fine when using a simple localhost origin, I'm encountering difficulties with subdomains.

Here's a summary of the steps I've taken and the problems I'm facing:

**Setting up a cookie at time of Login:**

```
res.cookie("token", token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: "none",
    path: "/",
    secure: true,
  });
```

When I try to get this cookie with my cors setting where the origin is :

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000", 
    credentials: true,
  })
);
```

But for testing when i use subdomain origin like :

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://binbros.localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
  })
);
```

There is no error with Cors from frontend and the cookie is created successfully at frontend
But when i try to access cookies with this cor setting i don't receive any cookie
But with the same method and Cors setting to simple Localhost, i get all the cookies without any problem

`console.log(req.cookies);`

P.S :
when im in localhost and orgin is loclhost
and i log cookie
i get all the frontend cookie not only the one i created in backend
BUT
when i am in origin of subdomain i don't even get 1 cookie in backend,
Not the one i created neither any one from frontend

Comment: _"Setting up cookie at time of Login"_ - is that code supposed to automatically specify the `domain` value of the cookie? If not, then you should explicitly do that - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#attributes: _"If omitted, this attribute defaults to the host of the current document URL, **not including subdomains.**"_

Comment: @CBroe So i should specify the domain im currently in right?
Also at the front end, i can see the cookie getting created successfully.
So does this mean declaring the domain in cookie is not the issue?

Comment: If you are "on" `localhost` when this cookie gets set, and the `domain` was not explicitly specified - then this cookie will only be valid for the exact host name `localhost`, and _not_ for any subdomains. It needs to explicitly have `domain=localhost` as part of the Set-Cookie header, to make the cookie available on `localhost` _and_ any subdomains thereof.

Comment: edited this Still no cookie received on backend:
res.cookie("token", token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: "none",
    path: "/",
    secure: true,
    domain: ".localhost",
  });

Comment: And how are you making the request, from the client side?

Comment: axios
        .post(
          "http://localhost:5000/api/auth/show",
          {
            email: userData.email,
          },
          {
            withCredentials: true,
          }
        )
this works fine with localhost ,not with subdomains

Answer (score 0):

When working with subdomains in a development environment like subdomain.localhost, there can be additional challenges due to browser security policies. Browsers often treat different subdomains as separate origins, which can affect the behavior of cookies and CORS.

**secure** property in the development environment is better to be **false**.

```
res.cookie("token", token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: "none",
    path: "/",
    secure: false,
  });
```

check your system **hosts**:

```
127.0.0.1 binbros.localhost
```

in frontend check is called apis from **binbros.localhost** domain or not,
and end check **Access-Control-Allow-Credentials**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

Comment: yes i have treid secure: false and withcredentials :true
im still not reciveing (any)cookies in the backend

Comment: read this article:
https://developers.livechat.com/updates/setting-cookies-to-subdomains-in-javascript